# self-opening OSX bash script to open ssh to remote terminal

Tags: bash, macos, ssh

Okay, first let me address how malicious this sounds: it sounds super malicious.

With that out of the way, let me explain what I'm trying to do. A coworker of mine has two Macbooks, one with a broken screen, several dozen GBs of photos of her grandchildren, and an external hard drive that she wants said photos transferred to. I want to remotely connect to the broken screen machine, find the photos in the file tree, and copy them all to the hard drive. I figure it's easiest to do this from the other mac, since macs play nicer together than other configurations.

I honestly have no clue to do this. Well, I know two things:

1.) The solution probably requires ssh.

2.) The 'screen' bash command seems promising, but I'm still wading through the documentation.

Beyond that, I'm lost.

Comment: SuperUser SE is a better place to ask about it :) (http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I'm literally brand new to SE, so I'm wont for guidance.

Comment: Actually, apple.stackexchange.com might be fine as well since it is about Apple products specifically.

Comment: Look up "target disk mode" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: That takes me here: https://support.apple.com/kb/ph10725?locale=en_US

Is there a way to do this wirelessly? I haven't the requisite cables.

Answer (score 1):

Another option since you have another Mac available is to try booting the Mac with the damaged screen in "Target Disk Mode". This in essence turns the Mac into an external drive.

Use Firewire or Thunderbolt Target Disk mode:

1. Turn off the ‘target’ Mac (the one who’s drive you want to show up on the host)
2. Connect both Mac’s to each other with the Firewire or Thunderbolt cable
3. Boot the target Mac while holding down the ‘T’ key until you see a Firewire or Thunderbolt icon displayed on screen (this signifies that target disk mode is detected and working).
4. In a few moments the target Mac will finish booting and the target Mac’s hard drive should appear on the host Mac’s desktop, allowing to access it like any other external drive.

When you are finished, safely eject the target Mac as if it’s any other disk
Once the target Mac has been ejected and disconnected it can be used as normal.

This option is very fast and is terrific for transferring large files, troubleshooting problematic Macs and performing some backups of critical files and data if a computer is misbehaving.

Though Firewire is no longer shipping on Macs, Apple has replaced FireWire with Thunderbolt as a high speed data connection on newer machines.

Answer (score 0):

One good strategy is to use `ssh` to connect, `cp` to copy the files, and `rsync` to double-check/retry copying.

```
ssh <coworker's login>@<broken mac's name>.local
nohup cp -a /Users/<coworker's login> /Volumes/<exernal hd>/. &
exit
```

Come back later and

```
ssh <broken mac>
```

Is `rsync` done?

```
pgrep rsync && echo "not done" || echo done
```

If done, then:

```
rsync -av /Users/<coworker's login> /Volumes/<name of exernal hd>
```

(Just to verify that the entire user folder successfully copied.)

Eject:

```
diskutil eject <name of external hd>
```

Use tab-completion to fill in the coworker's login and the name of the external hd.